# Variable UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I have a working UIImageView, but I want to change it based on a certain variable so I have this:
a string called imagevariable(which holds the value of image1 which is a png resource in my project).
So I have this:

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imagevariable" ofType:@"png"]];
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By wrapping the variable name imagevariable in quotes it is being treated as a string literal, try this instead

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imagevariable ofType:@"png"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing image variable as a string which means, that you will literally search for an image named "imagevariable.png". Instead take away that @"" and make it like this:

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imagevariable ofType:@"png"]];
```